# Запуск и контроль андроид приложения через IDE

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adb

Дано: установлено приложение на мобильное устройство (пример: Калькулятор), устройство подключено к компьютеру через кабель или вай фай.
Есть задача: Запустить приложение из IDE, выполнить определенный скрипт (написав на Джаве щелканье на цифры и получить какой-то результат.) 
С помошью ADB можно получить лист приложений. 
Но как осуществить все это в IDE? К примеру Eclipse? Есть конкретный пример?
Еще раз: приложение уже кем-то написано! Нужно его запустить и проверить что все работает как надо, но через IDE.

Comment: Нельзя так сделать. IDE - среда разработки своих приложений, а не хакинга чужих

Comment: Причем тут хакинг?! Как пример UISpy используемый для поиска IDs в десктопных приложениях. Нашел -> кликнул с использованием драйвера. Мне не нужен доступ к исходникам.